# Is it possible to withdraw a deletion vote?

Tags: discussion, deletion, undeletion

> Is it possible to withdraw a deletion vote?

Most probably not, but I want to be sure. (A few words about the motivation of not permitting this is also welcome.)

Comment: It is now possible to retract a vote to delete/undelete: see the [post by staff member Felippe Rangel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371279) on Meta SE. Additionally, note that a user can now only cast only a single vote each to delete/undelete on any given post, which is a change from the earlier mechanism: see [Felippe Rangel's answer to "Restrict the delete/undelete vote privilege to once per post"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371277) on Meta SE.

Answer (score 16):

The votes to delete, undelete, and reopen cannot be retracted. There is a feature request to change this: [Ability to retract reopen/delete votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/ability-to-retract-reopen-delete-votes)

Possible explanation: these votes are cast far less often than   close votes, and so the number of situations where a voter wishes to retract is proportionally smaller. In SE team's perception, it's not large enough to justify putting developer resources into this.

Things might change in the future... consider that the [request to retract close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/259867) was posted in June 2009 and implemented in July 2013.

Comment: The linked feature request on [metase] is now [status-completed]: see the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371279) there by the staff member [Felippe Rangel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/423506/felippe-rangel).