# Undeleting a deletion by an ex-moderator

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, undeletion

I found that I could vote to undelete [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112302/248286), deleted by Willie Wong, on 23rd of February 2012. According to his [Sheriff badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/307/sheriff?userid=1543), he was a moderator at the time, though obviously he is not any more.

I would think his deletion would be final, like other deletions by moderators. It seems like a bug to me, but maybe there's some rationale for allowing users to undo the work of previous moderators once they resign?

Comment: Some posts which seem related: [Deletion votes from users who later become moderators shouldn't prevent community undeletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174860) (Meta Stack Exchange), [Do the posts deleted by an ex-mod become undeletable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283913) (Meta Stack Exchange) and [Is moderator retirement supposed to affect possibility of undeletion?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294118) (Meta Stack Overflow).

Comment: Were you just experimenting, Theo, to see whether you could vote to undelete an answer deleted by a then-moderator, or did you really want to undelete an answer which only said, "well, never mind"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was experimenting. In fact, I chose to go through with it precisely because it was an answer that no-one could sincerely want undeleted. I wasn't even going to post it to meta, but after seeing it with one undelete vote (that I can't seem to retract), I felt like I had to explain myself. :)

Comment: OK, then, I feel much better. I think the way it works is that you can't change/retract a vote until the post has been edited, which you could do, if you really want to.

Comment: @GerryMyerson IIRC the possibility to retract vote after edit is for upvotes/downvotes - not for delete votes. See also: [Is it possible to withdraw a deletion vote?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20822), [Cancel delete vote](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4079) and the posts linked there.

Comment: I added a "by design" tag; it's at least a well-known issue (to SE).

Comment: @quid By (highly questionable) design it is then. I'd appreciate it if you would delete my undelete vote too, if possible.

Comment: There is no real way to remove the vote, I can just undelete and redelete, which I did.